# Onclick listener for (x) button in mancj/MaterialSearchBar

Tags: android

I'm using [mancj/MaterialSearchBar](https://github.com/mancj/MaterialSearchBar) in my Android app and I need to set an action for (X) button.
Is there anyway to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no option for X button click listener in this library. but when i look in to this library, i found that `mt_clear` is the id for your X button. there are two option for you to set action for your X button. make changes in library after import it manually. or give a try to find view by your `MaterialSearchBar` searchbar object like this.

```
materialSearchBarObject.findViewByID(R.id.mt_clear).setOnClickListener(yourClickListener):
```

Comment: thank you 
 materialSearchBarObject.findViewByID(R.id.mt_clear).setOnClickListener(yourClickListener) work fine.